PowerShell findWindow to Circle TAPS
I’m working on a PowerShell script that automates the opening of multiple Microsoft Edge browser windows with specific URLs. The script is intended to open five different websites, wait for a moment, and rotate the "views"
$URLs = @(
    "https://www.youtube.com", 
    "https://google.de", 
    "https://heise.de",
    "https://amazon.de",
    "https://f-i.de"          
)
$FensterTitel = @(
    "YouTube - Profil 1 - Microsoft Edge", 
    "Google - Profil 1 - Microsoft Edge", 
    "heise online - IT-News, Nachrichten und Hintergründe | heise online - Profil 1 - Microsoft Edge", 
    "Amazon.de: Günstige Preise für Elektronik & Foto, Filme, Musik, Bücher, Games, Spielzeug & mehr - Profil 1 - Microsoft Edge", 
    "Startseite | Finanz Infomatik - Profil 1 - Microsoft Edge"
)

$global:RotationAktiv = $true  

$EdgeProzesse = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    Write-Host "Öffne Edge-Fenster $($i + 1) mit URL: $($URLs[$i])"
    Start-Process -FilePath $EdgePfad -ArgumentList "--new-window", $URLs[$i]
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Write-Host "Alle Edge-Fenster wurden erfolgreich gestartet."

Add-Type @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public class WinAPI {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    }
"@
function GetWindow {
    param (
        [string]$fensterTitel
    )

    $hWnd = [WinAPI]::FindWindow([NullString]::Value, $fensterTitel)
    if ($hWnd -ne [IntPtr]::Zero) {
        Write-Host "Fenster gefunden: $fensterTitel"
        Write-Host "Fenster-Handle: $hWnd"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Fenster mit Titel '$fensterTitel' nicht gefunden."
    }
    return $hWnd
}
function Ansicht1 {
    $hWnd = GetWindow ($FensterTitel[1])
    if ($hWnd -ne [IntPtr]::Zero) {
        [WinAPI]::MoveWindow($hWnd, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, $true) #Vollbild
    }
}

function Ansicht2 {
    $hWnd = GetWindow($FensterTitel[2])
    if ($hWnd -ne [IntPtr]::Zero) {
        [WinAPI]::MoveWindow($hWnd, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, $true) #Vollbild
    }
}
while ($true) {
    if ($global:RotationAktiv) {
        Write-Host "Wechsle zu Ansicht 1."
        Ansicht1
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
 
        Write-Host "Wechsle zu Ansicht 2."
        Ansicht2
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 8

    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 
        Write-Host "Pausiert"
    }
}

[void]$form.ShowDialog()

Issue:
The script successfully opens all specified URLs in new Edge windows.
However, when I try to locate the windows using the GetWindow function, I always get a message indicating that the windows cannot be found.
Questions:
Why is the GetWindow function unable to find the Edge windows after they are opened?
Is there a better way to ensure that the windows are found and manipulated correctly?
Any help or guidance on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to set the process ID at the start, but then it does not find the process
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "msedge.exe" -ArgumentList "--new-window", $URLs[$i] -PassThru$EdgeProcessIds += $process.Id  # Store the process ID


What values do you see when calling GetWindowText on the browser Windows? Do they match the strings hardcoded in your script?

Does it make a difference if you pass $null instead of [NullString]::Value as the first argument when calling FindWindow?

You have defined the window titles in a variable $Title, but your functions Ansicht1 and Ansicht2 use the (undefined) array $FensterTitel

Thanks for your responses.
@OldBoy, the value is 0 because it couldn't find the window. Additionally, if you meant that I should try [WinAPI]::GetWindowText, I receive the error: "Error calling the method because [WinAPI] does not contain a method named 'GetWindowTextA'."

hanks for your responses.
@MathiasR.Jessen, it doesn’t make a difference; the result remains the same.

Thanks @Theo i already fix this, but same problem

Then please update your post so we can see it is fiixed

I have just tried something similar by enumerating the active Windows. By getting the text for each window that is found, I can check if the title contains the string  "Edge", which is a simpler way of doing what you want.

Try using EnumWindows instead of FindWindow, example implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78991989/15339544

Thank you, @OldBoy! This is a fantastic idea and exactly the answer I was looking for.

If you want do lock for the active Window:
$windows = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -ne "" } 
foreach    ($window in $windows) { 
if ($window.MainWindowTitle -like "*Edge*") { $fenster += $window.MainWindowTitle } } 
$windows = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -ne "" } 
foreach ($window in $windows) { if ($window.MainWindowTitle -like "*Edge*") {
$fenster += $window.MainWindowTitle } } 
$fenster

and if you want all edge windows:
you need the WindowHelper and this little code:
$script:fenster = @() 
$callback = {
    param($hWnd, $lParam)
    $sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 256
    [WindowHelper]::GetWindowText($hWnd, $sb, $sb.Capacity) | Out-Null
    $title = $sb.ToString()
    if ($title -like "*Edge*") {
        $script:fenster += $title 
        Write-Host "Gefunden: $title"
    }
    return $true
}
[WindowHelper]::EnumWindows($callback, [IntPtr]::Zero)
if ($script:fenster.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Keine Fenster mit 'Edge' gefunden."
} else {
    Write-Host "Gefundene Fenster mit 'Edge':"
    $script:fenster | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
}


Please don't forget to mark your reply as answer to help other guys that having the same issue.
